# C# Regarding for loop/ switch statement appropriateness. How to use an arrayList in switch statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, arraylist, switch-statement, refactoring

first question is regarding whether it would be better programming practice to leave this as is with a IF statement, or change it to be a switch statement.

```
 public Booking bookVehicle(String vehicleClass, Client potentialClient, int number)
    {
        ArrayList vehicles;
        if (vehicleClass.Equals("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Prestige Sedan");
        else if (vehicleClass.Equals("b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Luxury Sedan");
        else if (vehicleClass.Equals("c", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Full-size Sedan");
        else if (vehicleClass.Equals("d", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Mid-size Sedan");
        else if (vehicleClass.Equals("e", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Hatchback");
        else if (vehicleClass.Equals("f", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Compact");
        else vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Compact");

        if (available(vehicles, number))
        {
            ArrayList hiredVehicles = new ArrayList();
            int currentVehicle = 0;
            int hireCharge = 0;
            while (number > 0)
            {
                Vehicle thisVehicle = (Vehicle)vehicles[currentVehicle];
                if (!thisVehicle.hired)
                {
                    hiredVehicles.Add(thisVehicle);
                    hireCharge += thisVehicle.hireFee;
                    number--;
                }
                currentVehicle++;
            }
            return new Booking(potentialClient, hireCharge, hiredVehicles);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Booking(potentialClient, false);
        }
    }
```

So the above code is evaluating an ArrayList of vehicles, one of the attributes of vehicles is "Vehicle Class" by using an IF statement. Is it better to use a Switch statement why/why not??

Below is my code to try and achieve the same functionality as the above but with a switch statement, was going to put it into a seperate method that gets called but i dont know how with the arrayList.

```
    switch (ArrayList vehicles)
{
    case 'a':
        vehicles = thislocation.getVehicleClass("prestige Sedan");
        break;
    case 'b':
        vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Luxury Sedan");
        break;
    case 'c':
        vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Full-size Sedan");
        break;
    case 'd':
        vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Mid-size Sedan");
        break;
    case 'e':
        vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Hatchback");
        break;
    case 'f':
        vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Compact");
        break;
        default:
    vehicles = thisLocation.getVehicleClass("Compact");
        break;
return vehicles;
}
```

If you could please help me get this switch statement working to the same functionality as the if statement (if possible/appropriate) id greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `switch` statement specifies the variable you want to test the value of.

You're testing the value of the string, not the ArrayList:

```
switch (String vehicleClass)
```

As for the appropriateness of a `switch` block over an `if/else` block, that's a matter of opinion. Use whichever is easier for you to read and maintain.

Comment: Ok thankyou. 
would it be better to use a switch statement in this case??

Comment: Yeah ok i see, its for a refactoring assignment so i felt it might need to be changed just for reading standpoint. Also its quite a long one so it should be broken up i think, into maybe smaller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a way to avoid switch/if altogether. Have a dictionary with keys of strings a,b,c,d,e and entries of ArrayList that return the list of desired vehicles class, something along these lines:

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> vehicleDict = { 
{"a", thisLocation.getVehicleClass("whatever"}, 
{...}, 
{"e", thisLocation.getVehicleClass("some other class")} 
};
```

Then your initial part of the method becomes `ArrayList vehicles = vehicleDict[vehicleClass];`

Note 1: using an enum instead of strings would make this even better

Note 2: if this doesn't compile its likely because I'm typing on my phone.

Note 3: I didn't type out ever case; I'm sure you can do that. And of course, it's up to you to put the dictionary somewhere meaningful.